# get comment from website in java use jsoup

Tags: jsoup

this is my first time, I participate stackoverflow.com. Here is my question, I appreciate your help?
As title, get list comment and number of vote from website in java use jsoup, website example: http://www.techradar.com/reviews/phones/mobile-phones/iphone-6-1264565/review#null
Example: 
Comment: Seconded. Never had a problem either. An outright lie. 
Number of vote: 87
Comment: Lets try those iPhone only apps on an iPad and talk about resolution x1 or x2?
Number of vote: 40
Use jsoup, or anything else in java. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

This particular website using Disqus comment service , which means all comments will load to the page from third-party Server, you need to get the third-party link which in this example is :
[The Disqus link](http://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&version=d1b39333cdab5cb490d069fe62825a04&f=techradarlive&t_i=1264580&t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.techradar.com%2Freviews%2Fphones%2Fmobile-phones%2Fiphone-6-1264565%2Freview&t_d=iPhone%206%20review%20%7C%20Mobile%20Phones%20Review%20%7C%20TechRadar&t_t=iPhone%206%20review%20%7C%20Mobile%20Phones%20Review%20%7C%20TechRadar&s_o=default#2)

```
http://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&version=d1b39333cdab5cb490d069fe62825a04&f=techradarlive&t_i=1264580&t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.techradar.com%2Freviews%2Fphones%2Fmobile-phones%2Fiphone-6-1264565%2Freview&t_d=iPhone%206%20review%20%7C%20Mobile%20Phones%20Review%20%7C%20TechRadar&t_t=iPhone%206%20review%20%7C%20Mobile%20Phones%20Review%20%7C%20TechRadar&s_o=default#2
```

And then extract the comments using the class name or div : `Element mElement=doc.getElementByid("class name")` and dive into the class get the text Or 
Can use `Elements mElement=doc.select(div.mastrclass)`
with for loop you able to get the messages from Elements.

can use the same class to get the disqus link too.